# BYTE * Array in C#

Tags: c#, unmanaged-memory

I'm trying to call unmanaged function. I've called it from C++ by :
This is Test Project which working with me

```
// ConsoleApplication5.cpp : main project file.

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>

using namespace System;

typedef int(*Funcs)(int, BYTE (*)[90], BYTE (*)[90]);

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
BYTE Input[] =
        {
                    0x7f,0x06,0x02,0x66,0xd2,0x3e,0x4c,0x7f,0x50,0x0a,0x5a,0x3c,0xab,0x43,0x5d,0x51,0x47,0xe5,0    x94,0x49,0xbd,0xef,0xc2,0xe4
,0x6c,0xb1,0x3b,0x3d,0x7c,0x47,0x65,0x8f,0x67,0xa6,0xe8,0x6a,0xe9,0x0e,0xbd,0x93,0xad,0x4a,    0x31,0x68,0x82,0x02,0xe6,0x7e,0x01,0x36,0xa,
9,0x75,0xf7,0xa0,0xb9,0xe9,0x1b,0x09,0xba,0x19,0x8c,0x97,0x18,0x9c,0xcc,0xd8,0x87,0x0e,0x04    ,0xb3,0x7c,0xc2,0xbf,0x1e,0x42,0x3e,0x8b,0x64,0xf5,0x60,0x43,0x96,0xe7,0xf6,0x7d,0x54,0x84,    0x54,0x00
        };
            BYTE OutPut[90];
Funcs Funcis;
HMODULE x = LoadLibrary(L"E:\\Games\\Silkroad\\HackShield\\ehsvc.dll");
Funcis = (Funcs)GetProcAddress(x,"16");
Funcis(13,&Input,&OutPut);

FILE * pFile;
pFile = fopen ("myfile.bin", "wb");
fwrite (OutPut , sizeof(char), sizeof(OutPut), pFile);
fclose (pFile);

Console::Read();
}
```

but when i call it in C# by:

```
delegate int GetResponseD(int Code, byte[] Input, byte[] OutPut);
...
IntPtr hModule = LoadLibrary(@"###.dll");
IntPtr hFunc = GetProcAddress(hModule, "10");
GetResponseD Get = (GetResponseD)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(hFunc, typeof(GetResponseD));
GetResponse(13, Input, OutPut);
```

i get the first Byte only

Comment: Have you tried using the appropriate `MarshaAs` attributes on the delegate's parameters?

Comment: Who allocates the two arrays in C? The caller?

Comment: Judging by the code (the 13,&Input,&Output) it seems the arrays must be allocated by the function in the dll, right?

Comment: @xanatos Looks like the arrays are supposed to be allocated by the caller, based on the typedef and call in the C++ sample.  We need to see the definition of `Input` and `Output` from the C++ code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something similar, if the arrays are allocated by the method in the dll:

```
// You will probably have to free in some way Input and Output
delegate int GetResponseD(int Code, ref IntPtr Input, ref IntPtr OutPut);

static void Main()
{
    IntPtr input = IntPtr.Zero, output = IntPtr.Zero;
    GetResponseD grd = null; // something

    int res = grd(1, out input, out output);

    var input2 = new byte[90];
    var output2 = new byte[90];

    Marshal.Copy(input, input2, 0, input2.Length);
    Marshal.Copy(output, output2, 0, output2.Length);

    // Remember that you have to free input and output!
}
```

In C# you can't use unmanaged arrays. You have to copy their data in managed arrays (not entirely true, but true enough for what you need)

For the other calling mode try:

```
delegate int GetResponseD(int Code, ref IntPtr Input, ref IntPtr OutPut);

byte[] input = new byte[] {
    0x7f,0x06,0x02,0x66,0xd2,0x3e,0x4c,0x7f,0x50,0x0a,0x5a,0x3c,0xab,0x43,0x5d,0x51,0x47,0xe5,0x94,0x49,0xbd,0xef,0xc2,0xe4,0x6c,0xb1,0x3b,0x3d,0x7c,0x47,0x65,0x8f,0x67,0xa6,0xe8,0x6a,0xe9,0x0e,0xbd,0x93,0xad,0x4a,0x31,0x68,0x82,0x02,0xe6,0x7e,0x01,0x36,0xa,9,0x75,0xf7,0xa0,0xb9,0xe9,0x1b,0x09,0xba,0x19,0x8c,0x97,0x18,0x9c,0xcc,0xd8,0x87,0x0e,0x04,0xb3,0x7c,0xc2,0xbf,0x1e,0x42,0x3e,0x8b,0x64,0xf5,0x60,0x43,0x96,0xe7,0xf6,0x7d,0x54,0x84,0x54,0x00
};

byte[] output = new byte[90];

GetResponseD grd = null; // something

GCHandle h1 = GCHandle.Alloc(input, GCHandleType.Pinned);
GCHandle h2 = GCHandle.Alloc(output, GCHandleType.Pinned);

IntPtr p1 = h1.AddrOfPinnedObject();
IntPtr p2 = h2.AddrOfPinnedObject();

grd(13, ref p1, ref p2);

h1.Free();
h2.Free();
```

Check your byte sequence, I think there is a `,0    x94` somewhere and `9` without `0x` at the beginning of the third row.

From what I've seen, this method has multiple ways of being called, with the first parameter that acts as a "switch" and the other two parameters that are interpreted based on the first parameter.

Comment: @user2529018 We aren't psychic here, post some full C++ example of use code. Who allocates the memory? How are the Input and Output then accessed? Who frees the memory?

Comment: i dont have the source of dll but the dll is ehsvc.dll from HackShield

Comment: @user2529018 Have I asked the source of the dll? I have asked **post some full C++ example of use code**